# How to avoid JSON error when using webdriver?

Tags: python

My code was working fine earlier but now I am  running into a JSON error. Here is the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\tsteu\OneDrive\Desktop\open_site", line 6, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 38, in install
driver_path = self.*get_driver_path(self.driver)
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 29, in *get_driver_path
binary_path = self.driver_cache.find_driver(driver)
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 102, in find_driver
metadata = self.get_metadata()
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 136, in get_metadata
return json.load(outfile)
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json_*init**.py", line 293, in load
return loads(fp.read(),
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json_*init**.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\tsteu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

And here is the code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

What do I need to change?